# Calculating Odds of winning?

Tags: math

So I'm trying to calculate the odds of someone winning, so for example there are 1,000 tickets, 4 people buy 250 tickets that would mean they have 25% chance each.

So I looked at how http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/games/odds.php but it says 20% chance...

I'm not sure if I'm being stupid here or not... I'm unsure how to do this. so far I've done the following

p = 250 / (1000 + 250) * 100
but it gives me 20...

Comment: 250 / (1000 + 250)? Why did you add 250 in denominator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not think too much, the answer is obvious here:

```
P = 250 / 1000
```

Hence the probability to win is 25%.

The only reason where you should be using the formula `P = A / (A + B)` is the following:

You have A red balls and B blue balls and you want to know the probability of picking a red one amongst all of them. Then the probability is `P = A / (A + B)`.

Comment: I'm stupid haha, I went away for like 10 minutes came back and saw straight away. Thanks.

Comment: You are not stupid, sometimes you just need few minutes to figure out simple things :)

Answer (score 0):

Your A and B values are 750 and 250 respectively. It gives you 25%.

Reason: If the winning ticket is in 250 tickets which you bought, then you will win. This is why B = 250. But if it is in other 750, you won't win. So, your A is 750. `250 / (250 + 750) = 1/4 = 0.25`

Answer (score 0):

> but it says 20% chance...

I assume you're entering `1000` and `250` in that site's input fields?  Note how the input is defined.  It's asking for `A:B` odds.  Which means the *total* would be both numbers combined, and the `B` value is your chance of winning.

Consider the example by default on that page: `3:2` odds of winning.  That is, out of a total of `5`, `3` will lose and `2` will win.  So you have a 40% chance of winning.

So if you put `1000` and `250` into the inputs, then out of a total of `1250` there will be `250` winners, so any given player has a 20% chance of winning.

> p = 250 / (1000 + 250) * 100 but it gives me 20...

That's correct.

If there is a total of `1000` and there will be `250` winners, then it would be `750:250` odds, or `3:1` odds, which is 25%.  To verbalize it, you might say something like:

> In this contest, any given player has 250 chances to win and 750 chances to lose.  So their odds are 3:1.

If the tickets were distributed more oddly, each person would have individual odds which may not reduce to smaller numbers.  For example, if someone bought 3 tickets, their odds would be `997:3`.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is for an odds calculator for sports betting. But the question you have is to do with probability.

You are correct in answering that the odds for each of the 4 people is 25%.  Each person has a 250/1000 or 1/4 chance of winning.